# Спец символы в адресной строке

Tags: url

Как сделать символ "галочки" в адресной строке как в github- е?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отображение зависит от браузера. Некоторые браузеры, в том числе Firefox, преобразуют текст URL-encoded параметров к читаемому виду. Например, если пробел закодирован как `%20`, то он всё равно отобразится как пробел. При копировании ссылки она скопируется как URL-encoded.

Это поведение не является стандартным и реализовано лишь для удобства восприятия URL человеком. У разных браузеров разные способы отображения URL, разные настройки отображения и т. п.

Конкретно галочка — это символ ✓, что в URL выглядит как `%E2%9C%93`. Она [используется в Ruby on Rails для обхода бага IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3222013) версий 5–8, из-за которого текст параметров неверно интерпретируется.

Просто так, для красоты, символ вставлять мало смысла. Если вам не нужна поддержка IE8, то про этот приём можно забыть.

Comment: Какого именно бага?

Comment: @Qwertiy http://stackoverflow.com/q/3222013

Answer (score 3):

Вот так ваша строка выглядит если скопировать её из браузера в блокнот:
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=test

Спец символ заменен кодом.